# RUNDLL32.EXE MSHTML.DLL,PrintHTML with Javascript

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-7, mshtml, rundll32

I've been working on making a new invoice for our order processing system - however the groundwork for this system is very old and it's made by an external company so I can't change it.

For a few budget-based reasons, I've been tasked with updating the invoice to Code-128 barcodes which, for the unaware, use a small compression method (so that the data scanned in uses less* space than alternative barcodes), and a checksum to validate the data is right when scanned - which is awesome.

The issue here is of course the fact that I can't produce barcodes like this in pure HTML/CSS like is possible with Code-39. I'll need some form of script.
I've written (cut, pasted and culled the fat from) a small system using a version of jquery old enough to be supported by IE7. Everything works fine in my emulation - but not in the live system.

I've been told the live system uses a `RUNDLL32.EXE MSHTML.DLL,PrintHTML {Printer} {Filename}` command to send the pages to print. My research tells me that RUNDLL32.exe *should* support Javascript alone, but I assume this isn't the case when it's going through a HTML file.

Is there any hope that this is just a setting or piece of code I need to alter? Is there a better way to generate these codes that will work with the system I need to use? Any pointers would really go miles.

Many thanks